# Количество клавиш мыши в линукс

Tags: python, linux, мышь

Нужно узнать количество клавиш мыши, используя Python

Сделать это на винде можно так:

import win32api
import win32con

countMouseButtons = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CMOUSEBUTTONS)
print(countMouseButtons)

но как сделать на линуксе инфу не нашел, хоть и пробовал пробивать по названию перменной, на случай если они схожи в винде и линукск. Прошу помочь, заранее спасибо

Comment: Что если мышей подключено несколько?

Comment: ```/dev/input/mouse*```

Comment: @andreymal  Это курсовая работа по предмету, поэтому в такие дебри лезть не нужно, рассматривается случай с 1 мышкой)

Comment: 1. в качестве pointer-устройства много чего может выступать, так что самое сложное — выбрать, какое же устройство вам требуется (запустите `$ xinput` и посчитайте все устройства с классом `slave  pointer`). 2. ну а выбрав устройство, можно запросить, сколько **логических** кнопок им заявлено. например, спросив про mapping кнопок: `$ xinput get-button-map идентификатор`. 3. логических кнопок, как легко убедиться, значительно больше, чем физических. 4. насколько вижу, про к-во **физических** кнопок устройства x-серверу, увы, не сообщают.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а никто не говорил об иксе. думаю надо смотреть в /sys/

Answer (score 0):

Сколько кнопок в реальной мыше драйвер точно знать не может, но спрашивает у устройства. Ответ можно найти в файле `/proc/bus/input/devices` или подевайсно в `/sys/`

Трехкнопочная мышка (Logitech) выдает маску 16,17,18

```
$ cat /sys/class/input/mouse0/device/capabilities/key
70000 0 0 0 0
```

6 кнопочная мышка (a4tech a7) выдает маску что может все (мышиные) кнопки

```
$ cat /sys/class/input/mouse0/device/capabilities/key 
ffff0000 0 0 0 0
```

возможно умеет хардварное переназначение клавиш